# Some site appears to be taking our questions and generating spam Google results

Tags: discussion

When I searched Google for a [recent question I posed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151287/visualizing-region-unions), this came up:

[image: spam site?]

When you click it, it redirects you through something called "hidereferrer" to some ad (sometimes pornographic). So it seems that they're taking text from questions here, and then generating BS Google results with that text that link to sites and generate revenue for them. I'm pointing this out both as a warning to others not to click on these links and as a question: Is there anything we can do about it?

I recommend you **don't click on it**, but here's the [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiHgITKuaLVAhVM6IMKHUT-BrcQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathematica.holdanswer.com%2Fquestions%2F151287%2Fvisualizing-region-unions&usg=AFQjCNFC6VXpm-P0erZraRriEUjd5MQdfQ)...

Comment: When I searched for the phrase, "Visualizing region unions", I also found "www.underwise.com/questions/226798/visualizing-region-unions", which looks to be of the same ilk.

Comment: I seem to recall this being discussed on the main Stack Exchange Meta site; I shall look for that Q&A now.  I believe Stack Exchange Inc tries to quash these.

Comment: Yesterday, before reporting the "underwise" site to StackExchange, I again searched for such knock-offs and found "underwise" but not "holdanswer".  Today, the situation is reversed, with "holdanswer" back but "underwise" gone.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/158428)**

> #### How do I go about reporting these sites?
>
> Please [contact us](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) directly using the on-site form. Select
> the "**Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without
> attribution**" option from the drop-down, and provide as much
> information as possible. Even if you are reporting an entire site that
> is scraping many questions, please provide an example of a question on
> their site and the corresponding question on our site, as well as any
> Google search terms you used that led you to finding this site. Any
> other information you might have can be included in the free-form text
> box.

Also: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport

Comment: Shall I go ahead and fill out their form or have you already done so?

Comment: @Shane Please fill it out; I did not.